# Failure issues in Android Resource Linking

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I'm working on my very first project in android studio. activities were running smoothly even after I added action listeners against the buttons to switch between activities, But now It's giving me 2 errors "Android resource linking failed " in my second activity (XML). when I click on the error, it takes me to one of the buttons. I'm unable to find the root cause of this, can anyone please help me?
After Inspecting my code I did not find any errors but warnings.

Here's the XML code of the button:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/forgotPwBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="transparent"
    android:text="Click Here"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.073"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView9"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.617" />
```

while on the other hand, My Java code is:

```
    PasswordBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.forgotPwBtn);
PasswordBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openActivity2();
            }
        });



`public void openActivity2()
    {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, ForgotPassword.class);
        startActivity(intent1);
    }`
```

Comment: Can you post everything? Show me the xml from second activity the rest of your java code.

Comment: replace `android:background="transparent"` to this `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` because just `transparent` is not accepted

Comment: try reading the build output error on the right side

Comment: I agree to @L2_Paver. As he says "android:background="transparent" is not accepted".